# Is it possible to use a usb hub with a kvm switch?

Tags: usb, kvm-switch, hub

My preferred keyboard and mouse need 2 usb ports each (thanks, razer).

This has put me in a bind because I need to kvm for work purposes and none seem to be setup for kb/m that need 2 usb ports each.

Would plugging a 2 slot usb hub into each input slot on the kvm where I'd normally put the kb and mouse work?

The kvm switch I'll be using is powered from each of the PCs I will be using (2 PC, one monitor setup).

Comment: There's no such thing as a USB splitter. It must be a hub.

Comment: This is what I referred to as a splitter: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Splitter-Adapter-Female-Charging-Extension-Black-Red/dp/B079CGPVQD/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=usb+splitter&qid=1622447353&sr=8-9

Comment: "One Side Only For Charging" there's no such thing as a USB splitter. The protocol simply doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that! I'm going to edit my post to refer to usb hubs

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue with a Corsair keyboard.

So I took a self-powered USB hub, plugged in BOTH connections of the keyboard (and the wireless mouse dongle). Then connected the USB hub to the KVM.
And it works.

Most modern USB KVM switches will work with a keyboard/mouse attached by USB hub.
(Many USB dongles with a wireless mouse/keyboard set are actually USB hubs internally. If those work a separate hub will work too. The KVM can't really tell the difference.)

Please note that you will need a self-powered hub that can supply enough power for both devices. The KVM will not be able to power the USB hub and the devices on its own.

Comment: Same here with Corsair keyboard. Must we put both USB connectors on the hub, pra can we put the main one on the KVM (reduncing latency) and the secondary one on the hub, only for electric power?

Comment: @AndréWillikValenti Depends on the exact model of Corsair keyboard. Some use the 2nd usb for power while others use it ONLY as passthrough for the USB port in the keyboard. If the latter it has no electrical connection tintje keyboard itself

Comment: Mine is Strafe MK2, it's kinda 50-50. I have now only the main port connected. Works fine on Linux and Mac. On Windows, it works (almost) fine by setting iCUE to read input every 8ms (125hz) instead of the default 1ms (1000hz). In the rare case it didn't seem to work, connecting the second port directly to the PC made it work. This setup could not be made default because it stops the KVM from working at all when I switch between computers. I even considered adding a USB power supply and plug the secondary USB port to it. Probably a HUB (even a monitor with built-in hub) is a better idea.

Comment: Correction: it doesn't always work. You can't rely on connecting only one port. I'll try another setup with a monitor with built-in HUB and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

USB splitter doesn't exist, and if it existed then it would only do mirroring
of "something".

However, KVM for two USB ports seems to exist. A quick search found the
[ATEN CS22U KVM Switchbox - 2 Computer(s) - 1 Local User(s) - 2048 x 1536-6 x USB - 3 x VGA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G9LYBTN):

[image]

I only give this as an example and I have no experience with this device or
similar ones and cannot guarantee that they will work for you.

Comment: That's actually my current non-hdmi kvm but it only lets you plug in one usb per kb and mouse. I need 2 usb per kb and mouse.

Comment: You will need to keep on searching. Product recommendations are not allowed on our site, but a good solution must exist somewhere.