# Why doesn't any USB hub work with my KVM switch?

Tags: usb, kvm-switch

I have a [Lindy High Speed HDMI KVM switch](https://www.lindy.co.uk/kvm-c6/2-port-hdmi-usb-2-0-audio-kvm-switch-compact-p6899) for two PCs that switches HDMI and USB. The KVM switch provides two physical USB ports. But I need three (keyboard, mouse and WebCam). So I thought I'd plug in [a USB hub](https://www.proshop.dk/USB-hub/I-Tec-USB-30-Charging-HUB-7-port-Power-Adapter-36-W-USB-hub-7-ports-Graa/2851678) to get more USB ports. The KVM's page even says:

> Additional USB accessories can be attached using a USB Hub (not included)

But that doesn't work. When I've plugged in the HUB and switch PCs on the KVM, it works momentarily and then switches back to the other/original PC. Even if there is only one device connected to the USB hub. I've tried multiple USB hubs that otherwise work. Both ones with external power supplies ("self-powered"/"active") and ones without a power supply ("passive"), so I don't think it is a problem with the USB hub. The answers to this question: [Is it possible to use a usb hub with a kvm switch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1652659/is-it-possible-to-use-a-usb-hub-with-a-kvm-switch) seem to indicate that it should work, but it actually doesn't.

What could be the reasons why USB devices work when plugged in directly to the KVM switch, but that the KVM switches back to the original device after a few seconds when the USB hub is used - even if only one USB device is connected in the hub and even if the hub is "self-powered"/"active".

(Oh, and I need 4K HDMI or DisplayPort graphics support, but I'm pretty sure that is irrelevant to this.)

Comment: KVM switches are not all created equal.  So the answer to the question you linked to is accurate, but some KVMs, might not be applicable.  What I notice about your KVM is it doesn't have a USB port, specific for a third USB device, that isn't a mouse or keyboard unlike most KVMs. Those ports are USB 2.0 what type of HUB are you using?

Comment: Yeah, it is is a USB 3.0 hub. Do you think that is it?

Comment: I've just checked, and one of the USB hubs I tried was an (unpowered) USB 2.0 hub :-(

Comment: There is a very good chance.  What is more likely is your KVM despite claiming it supports USB Hubs does not actually support it.  There is actually nothing particular special about the Keyboard/Mouse other than the fact they are USB 2.0